# Does any function germ belong to its gradient ideal?

Tags: complex-analysis, commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Consider the $\mathbb C$-algebra $\mathcal O_2$ of holomorphic function germs on $\mathbb C^2$ at the origin $0$.
Is it true that
any germ $f\in\mathcal O_2$ with $f(0)=0$ belongs to $(\partial f/\partial x,\partial f/\partial y)$,
the ideal generated by its partial derivatives?

Comment: In general no. A deep theorem called Briancon-Skoda theorem will say that the square of $f$ will belong in this ideal locally. There are examples where $f$ itself may not.

Comment: A counterexample is $f=x^2y^2+x^5+y^5$ (so simple and so surprising for me!).
Concerning $f^2$, an even stronger is true:
$f^2\in(x\partial f/\partial x,y\partial f/\partial y)$.
This was conjectured by Mather and proved by Briançon-Skoda.
All this is written in Demailly's "Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry"
(Ch. VIII, Corollary 10.6).
I found it by the query "Briançon-Skoda theorem", thank you a lot!

Comment: You are welcome .